# Changing Numbers in Matlab Symbolic Expression

Tags: matlab

In Matlab, I have a symbolic variable f and I want to substitute all numbers less than 10^-5 with 0.

For example

```
f=sym('0.89445*x^3 + 1e-8*x^2 + 4*x + 1.8e-13');
```

should turn into:

```
0.89445*x^3 + 4*x
```

How can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

you could declare the constants before calling the sym function :

```
clear
clc
a = 0.89555;
b = 1e-8;
c = 4;
d = 1.8e-13;
if a < 1e-5
    a = 0;
end
if b < 1e-5
    b = 0;
end
if c < 1e-5
    c = 0;
end
if d < 1e-5
    d = 0;
end
symVar = strcat(num2str(a), '*', 'x^3', '+', num2str(b), '*', 'x^2', '+', num2str(c), '*', 'x', '+', num2str(d));
f = sym(symVar);
```

There is probably a better way than using 4 `if` to check and declare the constants equal to zero.

I just found a way: replace the 4 `if` by an anonymous function :

```
clear
clc
a = 0.89555;
b = 1e-8;
c = 4;
d = 1.8e-13;
h = @(x) x>=1e-5; 0;
symVar = strcat(num2str(a*h(a)), '*', 'x^3', '+', num2str(b*h(b)), '*', 'x^2', '+', num2str(c*h(c)), '*', 'x', '+', num2str(d*h(d)));
f = sym(symVar);
```

Let me know if this work for you.

Comment: Thanks, In some cases, this method helped me. But I wanted to see if there is any way to do this for some general variable (We do not know number of terms and functions in symbolic variable).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [sym2poly](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/sym2poly.html) to get the polynomial coefficients and the revert back to sym form with [poly2sym](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/poly2sym.html)

```
dummy = sym2poly(f);
new_f = poly2sym(((abs(dummy)>1e-5)) .* dummy,'x');
```

Comment: Thanks! But this function converts symbolic numbers to double, and therefore, some digits of long numbers will be omitted. Suppose f=sym('1.651657461965584988165165465168476874651*x');

Comment: I found [coefficients,terms]=coeffs(f). this doesn't convert sym to double.

Comment: +1 for [`coeffs`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/coeffs.html). `[ci,ti] = coeffs(f); f = sum(ci(ci>=1e-5).*ti(ci>=1e-5))`.